# Displaying an image from an SQL BLOB with PHP

Tags: php, sql, blob

I have two files, one to upload an image and another to retrieve it from the database and present it on the web page. However the image only appears as broken image icon. I do not understand why.

Thanks for any help in advance.

The HTML form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="image">File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

The php to upload it(The connection to the DB is left out below but it works perfectly):

```
//file stuff
$file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))  
    echo "Please select an image";

else {

    $image=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $imageName=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $imageSize=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if(!$imageSize)
        echo "Thats not an image you mong";
    else {

        //upload    
        $query="INSERT INTO store VALUES('','$imageName','$image')";
        $sendQuery=mysql_query($query);
        if(!$sendQuery)
            echo "This is embarressing. It didn't work";
        else {

            $lastid=mysql_insert_id();
            echo "Image was uploaded. <br>Your image:";
            echo "<img src=get.php?id=$lastid/>";


        }
    }    

}
```

The PHP to retrieve the image(Again the DB connection is left out below but works perfectly):

```
$id=addslashes($_REQUEST(['id']));

$imageQuery="SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id;";
$sendImageQuery=mysql_query($imageQuery);
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($sendImageQuery);

$image=$image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the the opening php tag is the very first line of the file. If the opening php tag is not on the first line of the file then content has already been written to the response causing calls to the header() function to be ignored.

```
<?php // this has to be on line 1

// do database connections stuff, no output can be sent to the response.
$id=addslashes($_REQUEST(['id']));

$imageQuery="SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id;";
$sendImageQuery=mysql_query($imageQuery);
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($sendImageQuery);

$image=$image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: I have purposely left out the php tags and db connection.

Comment: try it and see if it works. 9 times out of 10 that is the problem.

Comment: In the real files I have the php tags and the db connection. I have noted above that this is definitely not the problem.

Comment: have you confirmed that you have the image data assigned to $image? and that no output has been sent to the response prior to echo $image?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the magic quote setting (`magic_quotes_gpc`), try:

```
$image=stripslashes($image['image']);
```

You should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes()` and only if magic quotes are not enabled.